# Meteor iOS the entity Group is not key value coding-compliant for the key ""

Tags: ios, core-data, meteor, meteor-ios

I'm working on an iOS app that is to integrate with a Meteor server using [meteor-ios](https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios).

I've copied a lot of the utilites out of the swift todos example to try and load a list of objects from the meteor server and load them into a tableview.

When running the application, I end up with this exact error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Group 0x7ff494e3c850> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Group is not key value coding-compliant for the key "".'
```

I have absolutely no idea where to begin digging for this or what code to share for it so any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't used meteor-ios. But my guess is that somewhere in the code `setValueForKey:` is being called with an empty string.

Comment: @iosDev82 A little more background if it helps at all: I havn't actually done any setting as far as I know, so far I've only gotten as far as trying to fetch some data.

Comment: I've created a meteor-ios tag with the question. My guess is that maybe you've missed something out while setting it up. Just guessing blindly, maybe you're supposed to set value for this function somewhere.

Comment: It would make a big difference if you could add the code where this error occurs. The error message on its own just says you tried to access a key using an empty string. **Why** that happens is impossible to answer with the information provided so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The error message was throwing me off since I thought it was an assignment issue.

The problem was that I was passing an empty string to the fetched results controller like so:

```
NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "", cacheName: nil)
```

Switching `sectionNameKeyPath` to `nil` solved the issue.

Comment: Please accept this answer so that it no longer shows up on the list of questions needing answers. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, OK. Just try to remember to do so once you can.